# How to Fade Individual Hair Particles with Nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles, hair, shader-nodes

I've got these eyebrows made with a Hair Particle System using Interpolated Children. **I would like to fade each hair particle as it gets further from the base.** Red line is the base, green is where it would be fading to transparent.

So far, I have the particles so the base is thicker than the end which is good, but I want to fade them out even more. The material is pretty simple, just a couple of BSDFs mixed together.

I've tried to mess with Texture Coordinate or Particle Info with a ColorRamp as the Fac on a MixShader between a Transparent BSDF and the Hair Material, but it has only affected the entire particle systems, not individual particles in the system.

I am planning to render this in Cycles, so it would be nice if the solution worked in it.

[image: Eyebrows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a gradient from the root of the hair to the tip you can use a *Curve Info* node in the *Shader Editor*. You'll find it under <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add* > *Input*.

The *Intercept* output gives a gradient from 0 to 1 starting at the root and ending at the tip. To show this, I plugged it in a *Color Ramp* going from red to green like you showed in the question:

[image: hair gradient color]

This is just a *Principled BSDF* using it for the *Base Color* to color the hair, but you could also plug the (inverted) *Intercept* value into the *Alpha* input to make it slowly transparent.

Or if you are going to use a *Principled Hair BSDF* instead, this has no *Alpha* input. In this case you can use the *Intercept* value as a mix factor to combine it with a *Transparent BSDF*:

[image: mix hair with transparent]

Now it is up to you to tweak the settings until you find something you like.